# Is it possible to get print version of website as PDF in byte array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I'm writing a web application where you can print receipt for what your buying. 
I also want to be able to get the receipt via E-mail. I'm wondering, is there any way to get the print version of the page as byte array so I can send the PDF(as byte array) to my server and send the e-mail.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  Even if it were, I think it would be far easier (and much more efficient) to create this PDF server-side.  If you don't want to learn the API of some module to create PDFs,  you can always fire up PhantomJS and let it do the rendering of your receipt page for your server-side.

Comment: Yea your right, it's probably best to do this server side.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are libraries as http://parall.ax/products/jspdf That allow to you create a PDF in client side.

However, I think that do it in server side It could be a better solution for this case. But, It depends...